# How does childscope work on an ng-if statement? Specifically in a <SELECT> element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ng-show

NOTE: I'm a new member here so I couldn't directly comment and ask for clarification.

So, my question is: How can I work around ng-if creating a child scope for a select element?

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
        <select id="project-select" 
            ng-if="projects.length > 0"
            ng-options="project.name for project in projects" 
            ng-model="currentProject"
            ng-change="broadcastChange('project-changed', currentProject)">
        </select>
```

And my controller is set up in the following format:

```
function Controller() {
    //Do code stuffz
}
angular
   .module('app')
   .controller('Controller', Controller);
```

I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35260811/6535053) post that the "ng-if" is creating a child scope.

So even when the model changes, this part stays the same because it is a primitive value: (name is just a string)

```
<div id="current-project" class="pull-left">
    <strong>Project: </strong>{{currentProject.name}}
</div>
```

Furthermore in the aforementioned post there were a couple options.

a. Simply change to this: `ng-model="$parent.currentProject"` which feels a little hacky

b. Set the object value in the controller, which I'm not entirely sure how to do. I feel like it's an easy fix, but I'm somehow overcomplicating it.

Anyway, for now I simply changed `ng-if` to `ng-show` and that's solved the problem. However, I am trying to understand Angular more deeply and I feel like this issue could be explained a little bit better to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: yes, binding to an object property is the right idea @blitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will find with Angular scope variables is: always use a dot.

That's the mantra from the excellent [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/)

In your case, what this means is this:

You have this code:

```
    <select id="project-select" 
        ng-if="projects.length > 0"
        ng-options="project.name for project in projects" 
        ng-model="currentProject"
        ng-change="broadcastChange('project-changed', currentProject)">
    </select>
```

Which means that you are binding to a $scope variable called `$scope.currentProject`.

Because of the mysterious and awesome way that javascript works, this does **not** get updated when you are inside of a child scope.

Thankfully, the solution is actually quite simple.  Instead, create an object like so:

```
$scope.myData = {
    currentProject: ''
}
```

And in your markup, bind to that like so:

```
    <select id="project-select" 
        ng-if="projects.length > 0"
        ng-options="project.name for project in projects" 
        ng-model="myData.currentProject"
        ng-change="broadcastChange('project-changed', myData.currentProject)">
    </select>
```

And voila.  It will update, even though it's in a child scope.

This is actually quite useful, because you now have a way to "meaningfully" group variables together. Here's some other pseudo-code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
$scope.projectData = {
    currentProjectID: 1,
    currentProjectTitle: 'My Cool Project',
    projects: [
             {id: 1, name: 'My Cool Project'},
             {id: 2, name: 'Another Project'}
         ],
    someOtherProperty: false
    // ...etc....
}
```

As a side-note, this section of this article might be helpful: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm#jscript4-CHP-11-SECT-2.1

Comment: Okay, this was exactly the information I was looking for. I didn't fully understand that "object notation" meant simply nesting my currentProject object inside of a $scope object that held other $scope objects. Just for clarification, is it a bad practice to throw _everything_ that you're using for ng-model inside one big object like that? Are there performance implications?

Comment: In my projects, I put pretty much everything in objects, but I group them.  I may have 1, 2, 3, or more objects that pertain to the different "sets" of information I care about.  As for performance, all I can say is that we used this model on a pretty complex app that didn't seem to be impacted at all by this.  With angular, there's far more important "performance" things to be concerned about - limiting watchers, etc - this article (among others) may be helpful: https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show/hide the select element based on the projects in your 'Controller' controller scope, then ng-show is the right way to go here. In my experience, I've used ng-if when I'm conditionally loading a larger "partial" view containing numerous controls where I felt a separate scope was necessary to avoid having a very large scope (or to facilitate re-use).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Do not use `$parent` in any production Angular apps. It makes your model dependent on the structure of your view, which makes your code hard to refactor and less modularized.

Binding to object properties is the way to go, as you suggested in your "b" answer. The recommended way to do this in the latest version of Angular 1.x is by using the "controller as" syntax. This method makes use of "prototypical inheritance" in javascript. There is a good explanation on this here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance

I created a plunker for you to demonstrate how binding to object properties works in nested scopes. take a look at the "controller as" syntax". also, try changing the value of ctrl.testBinding in the input, you will see that reflected in the `ng-if` child scope. I will try to find some links to explain this in more detail.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Gx5xbkJXgzjPSG8kajPR?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">
      <input ng-model="ctrl.testBinding" type="text"/>
      <button ng-click="ctrl.toggle()">toggle show</button>
      <div ng-if="ctrl.show">
         {{ ctrl.testBinding }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>

//script.js
function testController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.show = true;
    vm.toggle = function(){
      vm.show = !vm.show
    }
}
angular
   .module('testApp', [])
   .controller('testCtrl', testController);
```